# Pythagoras' Theorem showing incorrect answer

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagram 1]

Given the diagram above, where I calculate y to be $11.3 = \sqrt{8.2^2 + 7.8^2}$ after square rooting the answer, to 1 d.p. Z therefore should be $10.1$, given by $11.3^2 - 5^2$, then square rooted?

This is flagging incorrect, can someone explain why?

Comment: what's the issue even?

Comment: Don't abbreviate unless you absolutely know that the abbreviation is well known. Took me a moment to realize "d.p." meant decimal place.

Comment: You rounded down to get $10.1$, it seems.

Comment: No, $z=\sqrt{8.2^2+7.8^2-5^2}$, not $+5^2$. @MoebiusCorzer

Comment: Note that you don't have to take the square root of $8.2^2+7.8^2$, since you are just about to square it again.

Comment: Well damn I'm awful at this. Thanks for the clear up. I was taking 1 decimal place answers throughout when squaring / rooting etc... Therefore my final square root ended up to be out by a few, causing me to round down. :/

Comment: You probably lost precision when you squared the approximation of a square root.

Comment: Try to avoid rounding to the last possible moment.  Compounded rounding leads to fairly large margin of errors quickly.  (margin of error of .1 becomes margin of error of .3 when you take a square root!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y=\sqrt{8.2^2+7.8^2}$

$z=\sqrt{y^2-5^2}=\sqrt{8.2^2+7.8^2-5^2}=
\sqrt{67.24+60.84-25}=\sqrt{103.08}= 10.2$ (rounded to one digit).

Note that if you approximate $y$ to one digit, you get $y=11.3$; then
$$
\sqrt{11.3^2-5^2}=\sqrt{102.69}=10.1 \text{ (rounded to one digit)}
$$
It's wrong to approximate $y$ before doing the complete computation, because you have to square it back and lose accuracy: indeed, the rounding of the “true” result to one decimal digit is $10.2$ and not $10.1$.

Comment: The answer was wanted to one decimal place, which meant the rounding should be $10.2$, since the value is $>10.15$.

Comment: Well damn I'm awful at this. Thanks for the clear up. I was taking 1 decimal place answers throughout when squaring / rooting etc... Therefore my final square root ended up to be out by a few, causing me to round down. :/

Comment: @AlastairWilkins I guess the exercise was exactly about that! :)

Answer (score 2):

By calculating $y$ first and *rounding* $y$, you get an error that causes the final rounding to be wrong.

If $y^2=8.2^2+7.8^2$ then $z=\sqrt{y^2-5^2}$. But you rounded $y$ so that $$\sqrt{y^2-5^2}\approx 10.13$. But using the original $y^2$ you get $z\approx 10.152$, which rounds to $10.2$.

Rounding twice in two different places is always going to introduce more error.

Note that while $y-11.3\approx 0.017$, $y^2-11.3^2=0.39$. By rounding $y$ to one decimal place, you've gotten a much bigger error in $y^2$.

---

**Side note:**

Assuming that the values $7.8, 8.2, 5.0$ were rounded to one decimal place, then the minimal value for $z$ is:

$$\sqrt{7.75^2+8.15^2-5.05^2}\approx 10.05$$

and the maximum value for $z$ is:

$$\sqrt{7.85^2+8.25^2-4.95^2}\approx 10.26$$

Of course, this does not take into account that the right angles were also just approximates :)

What this means is that, while $10.2$ is the correct rounding for this result, the error is more like $\pm 0.1$ than $\pm 0.05$. Rounding in computations is very
risky.

Answer (score 1):

Although to the nearest tenth $y = 11.3$, and $\sqrt{(11.3)^2 - 5^2} = 10.134$ which rounds to 10.1, if you carry $y$ to more accuracy you get $y=11.317$ wgich gives $z = \sqrt{(11.317)^2 - 5^2} = 10.153$ which rounds to 10.2.

In general, unless you have a really good grasp of the sensitivity of results on the uncertainties in inputs and intermediate results, you need to carry intermediate calculations (in this case, the square root done for $y$) to more decimals than you will require in the eventual answer.

Comment: This cleared up a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't need to take a square root until the end, and you can use $(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2a^2+2b^2$ to take most of the pain out of the calculation $$z^2=y^2-5^2=(8.2)^2+(7.8)^2-5^2=(8+0.2)^2+(8-0.2)^2-5^2=128+0.08-25=103.08$$

Then it is easy to see that $z$ is a little more than $10.15$ because $0.15^2=\frac 9{400}(=0.0225)\lt 0.08$ so to one decimal place you get $10.2$.

Rounding half way through gives you an answer a little below $10.15$.